# Dynamically create audio object based on audio streams in React state?

Tags: reactjs, webrtc

I'm creating a group voice call application through React and WebRTC.

I have the whole connection lingo between both peers working through my signalling server (remote descriptions, ICE candidates etc.).

I have not tested if it's functional because I can't figure out how to add audio elements for each audio stream present. I'm certain I'm doing it wrong but I'm sure you'll understand my logic.

I have this code for when the remote audio stream is being added:

```
   peer_connection.onaddstream = event => {
                console.log("On AddStream.");
                let remoteAudioObject;
                let remoteStream;
                remoteStream = event.stream;


            this.setState({remoteStreams: [...this.state.remoteStreams, remoteStream]});

            }
```

And to have the audio play, I created a separate React component called Audio manager, to which I pass in all the streams like this:

```
<AudioManager streams={this.state.remoteStreams}></AudioManager>
```

Inside:

```
export default class AudioManager extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);


    }

    render(){
        return(<div>
            {this.props.streams.map(stream => (
                <audio src={stream} autoplay></audio>
            ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
[object%20MediaStream]:1 GET http://localhost:3000/[object%20MediaStream] 404 (Not Found)
```

Would anyone have any pointers towards how I could accomplish my goal?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure but it looks like you are passing an object to `src={stream}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are passing incorrectly you source object.

`src={stream}` doesn't work is because `src` expects a string that represents the url of the audio resource while stream is a `MediaStream object`.

You should try something like this:

```
export default class AudioManager extends Component {
  setSrcObject(ref, stream) {
    if(ref) {
       ref.srcObject = stream;
     }
  }
  render() {
     return (
       <div>
         {this.props.streams.map(stream => (
             <audio ref={ref => this.setSrcObject(ref, stream)} autoplay />          
           )
         )}
       </div>
      )
    }
}
```